# Firebase REST orderby nested child of autogenerate ID?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I request firebase orderby nested child? My example data look like this:

```
ROOT
 |
 +-- post
 |     |
 |     +-- -LHRgRaBkEbh2J04sZcM
 |            |
 |            +-- vote: 1
 |     +-- -LHRgqbaxDTa5Jl6Wdar
 |            |
 |            +-- vote: 2
 |     +-- -LHRtsJhu4yl1vi4JS2X
 |            |
 |            +-- vote: 3
 |
```

According to firebase docs you can do it like this:

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="dimensions/height"&startAt=3&print=pretty'
```

but I can't do this since the parent node is autogenerated.

```
orderBy="parent/vote"
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database queries take each child node under the location you query, and then order them on the property you specify. So they automatically skip a single level, under the location you query.

```
curl 'https://your-db.firebaseio.com/post.json?orderBy="vote"&startAt=3&print=pretty'
```

Note that this **will** return the correct results (starting at `3`), but the results will **not** be ordered (since keys in JSON are by definition unordered).

Comment: awesome, thx! I got it working by adding .indexOn to the rule and this is working!

Comment: Can you give me some idea how to sort them by "vote"? assuming I have 1000+ posts. Should I load all the posts from firebase and sort them on the app? Will it decreasing performance & user experience in that way?

Comment: Figue it out. `limitToLast` did the job!