# How do I retrieve records in Firebase, via a Rest API, based on child value with multiple keys in its structure?

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I have the following structure in my Firebase database:

```
- Items (L1)
  -- key (L2)
    --- itemId (L3)
    --- itemName (L3)
    --- ....
- Orders (L1)
  -- key (L2)
    --- key (L3)
       ---- itemId (L4)
       ---- itemName (L4)
       ---- itemQty (L4)
```

I have the following index setup for orders.

```
    "orders": {
      "$custId": {
         ".indexOn" : "itemId",
        "$orderId" : {
          ".indexOn" : "itemId"
        }
      }
    },
```

I would like to pull all orders for a specific itemId (e.g. 1011).  I have tried to leverage the Google dinosaur example.  But, I couldn't get it to work perhaps because I have two key levels in my order structure.

I would like to write the request in as a RestAPI such as:
var url = 'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/orders.json?orderBy="itemId"&equalTo=1011';

Comment: You won't be able to get them all in one query.  You'll need two, one for Items and another for Orders.

Comment: In your current structure you can find all orders for a single customer with a specific item in them. You can't search all orders for all customers though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Thanks Doug - yes, I would know the itemId when I submit the query for orders with the itemId.

Comment: Thanks Frank - based on your links and prior readings, it sounds like I am not able to get all the orders containing a specific item based on my data structure. This said, I am still not sure why I can't achieve my objective.  In the following - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382047/firebase-rest-orderby-nested-child-of-autogenerate-id - the requester received an answer to search through a 'db generated key' level of the hierarchy. I want to accomplish almost the same - just through two 'db generated key' levels. If my comments don't make sense, I am happy to try to explain differently.

Comment: Based on reading other examples and these comments, it appears Firebase can only read one level down from a known value.  Since I have two levels of dynamic data, I am not able to accomplish my goal.  I will need to restructure my data.  If a solution exists without rearranging my data model, please respond.  Otherwise, I deem this closed.  Thanks BC